# Extacting entire table from HTML using python

Tags: html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) chrome/80.0.3987.132 Safari/537.36','Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9','Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate'}
# Get all get possible expiry date details for the given script
def get_expiry_from_option_chain (symbol):

    # Base url page for the symbole with default expiry date

    Base_url = "https://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/option_chain/optionKeys.jsp?symbol=" + symbol + "&date=-"

    # Load the page and sent to HTML parse
    page = requests.get(Base_url,headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')


    # Locate where expiry date details are available
    locate_expiry_point = soup.find(id="date")
    # Convert as rows based on tag option
    expiry_rows = locate_expiry_point.find_all('option')

    index = 0
    expiry_list = []
    for each_row in expiry_rows:
        # skip first row as it does not have value
        if index <= 0:
            index = index + 1
            continue
        index = index + 1
        # Remove HTML tag and save to list
        expiry_list.append(BeautifulSoup(str(each_row), 'html.parser').get_text())

    # print(expiry_list)
    return expiry_list # return list

def get_strike_price_from_option_chain(symbol, expdate):

    Base_url = "https://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/option_chain/optionKeys.jsp?symbol=" + symbol + "&date=" + expdate[0]

    page = requests.get(Base_url,headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

    table_cls_2 = soup.find(id="octable")
    req_row = table_cls_2.find_all('tr')

    strike_price_list = []
    temp_list=[]
    for row_number, tr_nos in enumerate(req_row):

        # This ensures that we use only the rows with values
        if row_number <= 1 or row_number == len(req_row) - 1:
            continue

        td_columns = tr_nos.find_all('td')
        strike_price = int(float(BeautifulSoup(str(td_columns[11]), 'html.parser').get_text()))
        strike_price_list.append(strike_price)



    # print (strike_price_list)
    return strike_price_list


sys="SBIN"
exp=get_expiry_from_option_chain(sys)
a=get_strike_price_from_option_chain(sys,exp )
```

can someome please help? 
I have the code to extract specific columns of a table of HTML but dont know how to get the entire table ..Can anyone please help me ?need to get the entire option chain so that i can do my analysis...............................................................................................................................................

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [comprehension list](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to extract all `td` inside all `tr`. You can also make a list of all the `th` to get the table headers and map them to the values :

```
def get_entire_table(symbol, expdate):
    r = requests.get(url, params = {"symbol": symbol, "date": expdate[0]}, headers = headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
    tr = soup.find(id = "octable").find_all("tr")
    th = [ 
        t.text
        for t in tr[1].find_all("th")
    ]
    return [
        {
            th[i]: t[i].text.strip() for i in range(1,22)
        }
        for t in (t.find_all('td') for t in tr)
        if len(t) >= 22
    ]
```

The whole code would be :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) chrome/80.0.3987.132 Safari/537.36','Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9','Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate'}
url = "https://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/option_chain/optionKeys.jsp"

def get_expiry_from_option_chain (symbol):
    r = requests.get(url, params = {"symbol": symbol, "date": "-"}, headers = headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
    return [
        i['value']
        for i in soup.find(id = "date").find_all("option")
        if i['value'] != "select"
    ]

def get_entire_table(symbol, expdate):
    r = requests.get(url, params = {"symbol": symbol, "date": expdate[0]}, headers = headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
    tr = soup.find(id = "octable").find_all("tr")
    th = [ 
        t.text
        for t in tr[1].find_all("th")
    ]
    return [
        {
            th[i]: t[i].text.strip() for i in range(1,22)
        }
        for t in (t.find_all('td') for t in tr)
        if len(t) >= 22
    ]

exp = get_expiry_from_option_chain("SBIN")
table = get_entire_table("SBIN", exp)

print(exp)
print(table)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer
This is not able to extract all the tables.

Comment: Hi, 
This is still missing one half of the table can someone please help me out